# Windows Phone 8.1 with Xamarin Forms and WCF service

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

Exist any incompatibility of Windows Phone 8.1 with WCF services ??

I'm developing an Xamarin Forms App Portable that use WCF services, in Android works ok but in Windows Phone 8.1 not work and there no errors or exceptions.

I add the Service Reference from Visual Studio and use it on this way:

```
IServicioWeb service = new ServicioWebClient();

var res = servicio.BeginMyValidateMethod(param1, param2, null, null);
var res_client = servicio.EndMyValidateMethod(res);
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code?

Comment: I'll edit the question to give more details, but really there is little code, only the configurations.

Comment: It just doesn't work with no exceptions? Are you sure CLR exceptions are enabled? Debug -> Exceptions, tick CLR or if you're using VS15: Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a REST implementation as it says [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/9ab43a4c-499a-4f2e-81e5-c1ab5acbe9bf/wcf-add-service-reference-not-supported-for-windows-phone-81-xaml-applications?forum=wpdevelop):

> Windows Phone 8.1 XAML applications does not support the
>   System.ServiceModel namespace, and therefore you are not able to right
>   click references in the project and choose Add Service Reference.
>   The recommended solution is to add a REST endpoint to your WCF
>   endpoint, and access the WCF application through the REST endpoint
>   using HttpClient.

Comment: Is true, but change the service is not in my hand. It looks a big error, that the Microsoft OS Mobile, not works with WCF, a Microsoft technology.

Comment: Actually it's an improvement because now we can use our REST method, modify them, add new methods without re-build and deploy our client mobile projects.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not sure, i can work with WCF in iOS and Android without problems. In my opinion the two ways should be implemented.

Comment: The real problem is when you need to maintenance your web service code an create new methods, versioning them: with WCF we need to re-build our projects to have the latest version of our WCF references. That's not a real problem for a lot of enterprise solutions but it doesn't a good practice. Personally I love using WCF because I have strongly-typed entities without such effort like using REST, but that's only because the projects I developed need it and my little expertise on the development field.